Ошибка psycopg2.OperationalError. connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Эта ошибка выходит при тестах. Если все тесты уберу, то соединение в порядке, все работает. Для тестов создал отдельную db_test под тем же юзером, пароль и локалхост и порт. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Что я не так делаю.

А права на тестовую базу такие же как на основную?

@CrazyElf вроде как да, а как это можно проверить? ЛОкально у меня работает, а вот CI на github action выдает эту ошибку соединения.
